# how do i handle a json data in csv file in python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv

I am currently doing a project on data analysis [on the tmdb dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/tmdb/tmdb-movie-metadata) in kaggle (BTW I'm a complete noob so plz forgive my ignorance) where I encountered the following column(2nd column) in the dataset:- `

genres

```
[{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 14, "name": "Fantasy"}, {"id": 878, "name": "Science Fiction"}]
[{"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 14, "name": "Fantasy"}, {"id": 28, "name": "Action"}]
[{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 80, "name": "Crime"}]
[{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 80, "name": "Crime"}, {"id": 18, "name": "Drama"}, {"id": 53, "name": "Thriller"}]
[{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 878, "name": "Science Fiction"}]
[{"id": 14, "name": "Fantasy"}, {"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}]
[{"id": 16, "name": "Animation"}, {"id": 10751, "name": "Family"}]
```

Here genres is the column name and the data in each row of this column are enclosed in []

What i want do is convert this in the following type fo column(the separator could be any thing except ',' since it is a CSV file:-

```
genres
Action;Adventure;Fantasy;Fiction;
Adventure;Fantasy;Action;
Action;Adventure;Crime;
And so on...
```

Here's my code:-

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import csv

reviews = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/HP/Desktop/data science project/tmpd second attempt/2. prepared data/tmdb_5000_movies.csv")

print(reviews["genres"]);
```

PS:-This is my first project so really don't know how to handle this

Answer (score 0):

That is not a csv file. It is a json file. so if you change

```
reviews = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/HP/Desktop/data science project/tmpd second attempt/2. prepared data/tmdb_5000_movies.csv")
```

to

```
reviews = pd.read_json("C:/Users/HP/Desktop/data science project/tmpd second attempt/2. prepared data/tmdb_5000_movies.csv")
```

it should work.

Oh and you might want to change the file extension from `.csv` to `.json`

Re comment from op:

This code works on your sample, bit of a hack but best I can do quickly:

```
import ast
with open("untitled.csv") as fi:
    data=fi.readlines()
cleaned = []
for da in data:
    l = da.strip("[").strip('\n').strip(']').split(', {')
    for a in l:
        pre=''
        if not a.startswith("{"):
            pre='{'
        cleaned.append(ast.literal_eval(pre+a))
df = pd.DataFrame(cleaned)
```

Comment: Sir, what I showed you was just a column in the csv file , the rest of columns are simple columns filled with number values such as id, budget ,etc, however this column is different as it contains json data and i don't how to convert it in that form

Comment: Good point see amended answer. Oh and Paula is a female name.

Comment: Thnks ma'am(srry for that 'sir')...I am going to try it